# renaming files and the interaction between printf and bash in the MacOS

Tags: bash

How to explain these outputs below? Why the second command replaces 010 with 0008? Maybe I didn't understand what is going on in the curly bracket syntax of bash:

```
$ BN=CF001; echo `printf CF%04d.conllu ${BN/CF/}`
CF0001.conllu
$ BN=CF010; echo `printf CF%04d.conllu ${BN/CF/}`
CF0008.conllu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force `bash` to treat the value as a base-10 number:

```bash
$ BN=CF010
$ printf '%04d\n' ${BN#CF}
0008
$ printf '%04d\n' $((10#${BN#CF}))
0010
```

Comment: Can you point me a bash tutorial or documentation that teach me all these modifiers and the `#` and `#{}` operators?

Comment: The `<base>#` operator is documented in the man page under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION. Notice that `#{}` isn't an operator; `${BN#CF}` expands to a numeric *literal* before the arithmetic expansion `$((...))` evaluates `10#...` as a base-10 literal. An excerpt from the man page: "Otherwise,  numbers  take  the  form
       [base#]n,  where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64
       representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that  base."

Comment: But why the expansion happens with `${BN#CF}` and `${BN/CF/}` ? If it is not an operator , what is it ?

Comment: The parameter expansion happens first, turning `$((10#${BN#CF}))` into $((10#010))`. Next, the arithmetic expansion sees the expression `10#010` and correctly parses and evaluates it as a base-10 numeric literal. There is no`#{...}` operation; there was only `...#${...}`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `d` modifier (number) in `printf`, that is interpreting `010` as an octal number since it start with `0`.

Octal number `010` is `8` in decimal (base 10).

You can use `s` to get right output:

```
BN=CF010; printf 'CF%04s.conllu\n' "${BN/CF/}"
CF0010.conllu
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I found, similar to @anubhava, is the use of `f`:

```
$ BN=CF010; echo `printf CF%04.f.conllu ${BN/CF/}`
CF0010.conllu
```